# Text analytics Vs text mining

Tags: information-retrieval

Most authors use Text analytics and Text mining interchangeably, But I think there is a distinction between this. Can any body briefly describe there difference?

Comment: https://www.decisionanalyst.com/analytics/textmining/

Answer (score 2):

Although both of the terms can be used interchangeably sometimes. Still one of the main difference is that mining follows analytics. Text analytics is a superset of text mining. Text mining involves cleaning, extraction and transformation of unstructured text into a structured form of database for computation. While text analytics is a process of applying the statistical algorithms on mined text for the extraction of knowledge. Text analytics is a product of text mining.

For detailed information: Visit https://www.educba.com/text-mining-vs-text-analytics/

Answer (score 1):

Text mining and text analytics are near synonyms for all practical purposes. A difference is that both terms are used in different contexts by different people. Text analytics is mostly used in a business context, whereas text mining is more of an academic term. The same applies for data mining and data analytics.